# WSO2 ESB RabbitMQ AMQP transport parameters

Tags: wso2, rabbitmq, rabbitmq-exchange, wso2-esb

I'm using a RabbitMQ Inbound endpoint to receive messages send to an exchange.

Everything runs fine, the queue and the exchange are created on Rabbit, but the exchanges paremeters are not applied, like the exchange type and durability.

I tried to change the exchange type to topic, fanout and headers, but always stay the as direct, the default configuration.

How I can configure the exchange type and other parameters?

This is my endpoint code:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<inboundEndpoint name="MessageInbound" protocol="rabbitmq" sequence="RabbitInbound" statistics="enable" suspend="false" trace="enable" xmlns="http://ws.apache.org/ns/synapse">
    <parameters>
        <parameter name="sequential">true</parameter>
        <parameter name="coordination">true</parameter>
        <parameter name="rabbitmq.connection.factory">connection_factory</parameter>
        <parameter name="rabbitmq.server.host.name">localhost</parameter>
        <parameter name="rabbitmq.server.port">5672</parameter>
        <parameter name="rabbitmq.server.user.name">guest</parameter>
        <parameter name="rabbitmq.server.password">guest</parameter>
        <parameter name="rabbitmq.queue.name">queue</parameter>
        <parameter name="rabbitmq.queue.durable">true</parameter>
        <parameter name="rabbitmq.exchange.name">exchange</parameter>
        <parameter name="rabbitmq.exchange.type">topic</parameter>
        <parameter name="rabbitmq.exchange.durable">false</parameter>
        <parameter name="rabbitmq.exchange.auto.delete">false</parameter>
    </parameters>
</inboundEndpoint>
```